# Transforming shapefiles to dataframes with shapefile_to_dataframe() helper function - fiona related error

Tags: palantir-foundry

I am trying to use the Palantir Foundry helper function shapefile_to_dataframe() in order to ingest shapefiles for later usage in geolocation features.

I have manually imported the shapefiles (.shp, .shx & .dbf) in a single dataset (no access issues through the filesystem API).

As per documentation, I have imported geospatial-tools and the GEOSPARK profiles + included dependencies in the transforms-python build.gradle.

Here is my transform code, which is mostly extracted from the documentation:

```
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output, configure
from geospatial_tools import geospatial
from geospatial_tools.parsers import shapefile_to_dataframe

@geospatial()
@transform(
    raw = Input("ri.foundry.main.dataset.0d984138-23da-4bcf-ad86-39686a14ef21"),
    output = Output("/Indhu/InDhu/Vincent/geo_energy/datasets/extract_coord/raw_df")
)
def compute(raw, output):
    return output.write_dataframe(shapefile_to_dataframe(raw))
```

Code assist then become extremely slow to load, and then I am finally getting following error:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'fiona' has no attribute '_loading' (most likely due to a circular import)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/myproject/datasets/shp_to_df.py", line 3, in <module>
    from geospatial_tools.parsers import shapefile_to_dataframe
  File "/scratch/standalone/3a553998-623b-48f5-9c3f-03de7e64f328/code-assist/contents/transforms-python/build/conda/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geospatial_tools/parsers.py", line 11, in <module>
    from fiona.drvsupport import supported_drivers
  File "/scratch/standalone/3a553998-623b-48f5-9c3f-03de7e64f328/code-assist/contents/transforms-python/build/conda/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fiona/__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    with fiona._loading.add_gdal_dll_directories():
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'fiona' has no attribute '_loading' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Thanks a lot for your help,
Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this error and it seems like it happens only in previews - running the full build seems to be working fine. The simplest way to get around it is to move the import inside the function:

```py
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output, configure
from geospatial_tools import geospatial

@geospatial()
@transform(
    raw = Input("ri.foundry.main.dataset.0d984138-23da-4bcf-ad86-39686a14ef21"),
    output = Output("/Indhu/InDhu/Vincent/geo_energy/datasets/extract_coord/raw_df")
)
def compute(raw, output):
    from geospatial_tools.parsers import shapefile_to_dataframe
    return output.write_dataframe(shapefile_to_dataframe(raw))
```

However, at the moment, the function `shapefile_to_dataframe` isn't going to work in the Preview anyway because the full `transforms.api.FileSystem` API isn't implemented - specifically, the functions `ls` doesn't implement the parameter `glob` which the full transforms API does.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes sense. I didn't know preview and build could be different...